# characteristic roots of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let the matrix
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
40 & -29 & -11 \\
-18 & 30 & -12 \\
 26 & 24 & -50 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$ 
have a certain complex number $p \neq 0$ as an eigenvalue. Which of the following must also be an eigenvalue of $A$?

1. $p+20$
2. $p-20$
3. $20-p$
4. $-20-p$

Comment: Can you tell us why you cannot solve this? This should be quite standard.

Comment: @user32240 Also being an Indian, I can tell that this is a question from some competition and she wants be sure if her solution is correct.

Comment: Are those column vectors , row vectors?

Comment: @diimension I don't think it really matters in this context, the eigenvalues are invariant under transpose.

Comment: @EuYu I have much to learn :)

Comment: @diimension As do we all :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $0$ is an eigenvalue, and the sum of the eigenvalues is the trace.

Answer (score 0):

Add column 2 and column 3. You will notice that sum is negative of column 1. Thus the matrix's determinant is 0. When the determinant of a matrix is zero, what we can say about one of it's eigenvalue?

Then go for trace of a matrix and its relation with eigenvalues of a matrix.